# Android WIFI/2G Switch - Which part of Android Framework handles it?

Tags: android, wifi, android-framework

when wifi is available, the network automattically connects from 2g to wifi? where is this handled in Android framework? I am currently working on ethernet driver for Android(X86-asus notebook). The ethernet driver is up and functional. I need to make changes in the existing framework so that it handles the switching part effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ConnectivityManager for  3G/EDGE and fot the wifi the BroadcastReceiver (as a call)

Check those projects : [WIFI SWITCHER](http://android-er.blogspot.be/2011/01/turn-wifi-onoff-using.html) and [RadioSwitchActivity](http://code.google.com/p/android-3g-to-2g-alert-notification-task-switch/source/browse/trunk/3g-to-2g-switch/src/com/gtug/hack/herbert_bangdao/Activities/RadioSwitchActivity.java?r=15)

Comment: Thanks @clement The links show hot to switch between wifi and mobile networks. Through some links in SO, i have found that, But i want to implement and give the application some api's similarly for ethernet. So where in Framework, i need to make changes is my basic question.